# How to prevent a dialog box from opening in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, javascript

I have to visit a website in a regular basis that reminds me it was originally designed for Internet Explorer 8 and Mozilla Firefox 3.5.12 to 3.6.10. It displays a dialog box with that warning everytime I load the site. I tried reloading Chrome a few times so it'd ask me if I wanted to ignored those warnings but it didn't work.

What can I do to ignore this specific warning? Alternatively, what can I do to ignore any scripted dialog box?

Comment: That's the worst design decision I've ever heard...I'd mail the site creator in addition to any other solution you find.

Comment: can you provide a link? what kind of dialog box is this? maybe you could add specific css/js over a plugin to hide the dialog by default.

Comment: @BenBrocka Yep, it's like something from back in the days of Netscape Navigator and IE4...

Comment: @BenBrocka IBM ClearQuest behaves this way. They update the "allowed browser list" between versions, but that doesn't mean the OP's organization keeps it up-to-date. Anyway I know it's a late comment but just wanted to put the "ClearQuest" keyword on this page in case anyone is looking for a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To disable JavaScript on a specific site, add it to Chrome's JavaScript exceptions list.

[image: Chrome JavaScript exceptions list]

Visit this page: `chrome://chrome/settings/contentExceptions#javascript` > Enter host url > Under Behavior choose Block. Do note, this would also disable all other JavaScript feature on the specified URL.

**Update:** See if [Better Pop Up Blocker](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nmpeeekfhbmikbdhlpjbfmnpgcbeggic) helps.

> Better Pop Up Blocker improves the default Google Chrome pop up
>   blocker by blocking pop up windows opened by javascript & other
>   annoyances that it misses like alert, prompt, and confirm boxes.

Comment: Unfortunately I need many data that needs javascript to be retrieved in this site. Can it be set to block javascript only in the main page? When I tried inserting a longer adress it removes whatever goes after '.com/'

Comment: I have updated my earlier answer. Check if it solves your issue.

Comment: Thank you! The second extension has a lot more options and it was possible to block only the one at the front page by selecting "Prompt & alert boxes" only.

Comment: The better pop up blocker extension link doesn't work. Has the extension been removed?